# Whats the right syntax for the string comparison query involving variable name in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

Suppose I have a Table Name

```
First Name      Last Name
--------------------------
Kris             Kristos
```

I want  a right syntax for the query which appears like

```
Select * 
from Name 
where First_name like '%'Last_Name'%'
```

Comment: Where do you execute this query from? A programming language / PostgreSQL function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `strpos`:

```
SELECT *
FROM name
WHERE strpos(LastName, FirstName) > 0;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cdbef/1/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer. 'concat' can be used for this purpose.

```
Select * 
from name 
where firstname like concat('%',lastname)
```